# Setting simplejson.JSONEncoder.default not working

Tags: python, encoding, simplejson

I'm trying to overrule the default encoder of simplejson. I have tried two approaches.

Using cls:

```
class ExtendedJSONEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, float):
            return '{0:.8f}'.format(obj)
        return super(ExtendedJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)

def save_signal(self, signal):
    with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(simplejson.dumps(signal, cls=ExtendedJSONEncoder))
```

Using default:

```
def extended_JSONEncoder(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, float):
        return '{0:.8f}'.format(obj)
    return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(obj)

def save_signal(self, signal):
    with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
                outfile.write(simplejson.dumps(signal, default=extended_JSONEncoder))
```

In both cases the extended JSONEncoder is not called.

This is an example of the data that I'm processing.

```
signal = {
    'pair': 'BTC-XRP',
    'term': None,
    'exchange': None,
    'entry_min': 8.5e-05,
    'entry_max': None,
    'stop_loss': None,
    'targets': [9.4e-05, 0.000105, 0.000118],
    'risk': 'medium',
    'strategy': 'targets',
    'enabled': True,
    'test_mode': False,
    'msg_id': 214,
    'msg_timestamp': '2018-03-05 20:01:52',
    'channel_id': '1234',
    'channel_name': 'realtime_sig'
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this maddening problem?

Comment: Please reduce your program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Simplified the code example and added an example of the json data that is written to the file.

Answer (score 3):

Don't override the `default` encoder function by monkey-patching the `JSONEncoder` class. As you've seen, that won't have any effect. Instead, pass an appropriate function to `dump()` or `dumps()`.

Here is a demonstration:

```
import simplejson

class C:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

def json_encoder(obj):
    print("WooWoo! Called!", obj)
    if isinstance(obj, C):
        return obj.item
    raise TypeError(repr(obj) + " is not JSON serializable")


with open('save.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(simplejson.dumps([1,C(47),C('orange'),4], default=json_encoder))
```

A deprecated alternative is to subclass `JSONEncoder` and pass the resulting class to `dumps()` via the  `cls` parameter.

```
import simplejson

class C:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

class json_encoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        print("WooWoo! Called!", obj)
        if isinstance(obj, C):
            return obj.item
        raise TypeError(repr(obj) + " is not JSON serializable")

with open('save.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(simplejson.dumps([1,C(47),C('orange'),4], cls=json_encoder))
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the quick response. I tried your approach. Using default doesn't work and nether does cls :-( I have updated my original question to reflect what I have tried.Would you mind double checking that I haven't done something stupid? Thx.

Comment: There is one obvious possibility that I've overlooked -- your data. The `default()` function is only invoked when the JSON encoder encounters a type that it cannot serialize on its own. It is possible that there is no such value in your data.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The data contains multiple floats. I have also set a breakpoint in the function and it never reaches it. I have added an example of the json data.

Comment: `float` is a supported type in JSON, so the standard JSONEncoder handles them internally. Given your example dataset, I wouldn't expect  your `default()` function to ever be invoked.

Comment: I added an example of the data. I do not understand why the code would not be called. Aren't the named parameters default and cls overruling the default JSONEncoder implementation?

Comment: @nidkil - No. Those do not override the default JSONEncoder implementation. `.default()` is only invoked when JSONEncoder finds an unknown type.

Comment: Hmmmm, I should have figured that out myself :-) Thx for the help Rob!